# Why does Python stall when running GoogleSearch script?

Tags: python, dictionary, google-search

My Python program stalls at the same point when running a script to scrape Google search results. The parameters are set to avoid Error 429 (Too Many Requests) and timing out. When the program runnings it goes to either the 43rd instance or the For loop or the 13th.

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

try:
    from googlesearch import search
except ImportError:
    print("No module named 'google' found")


user_agent_list = [
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.1 Safari/605.1.15',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36',
]

resultLinks = []

FIPSdictionary ={1:'New York', 2:'Los Angeles', 3:'Chicago', 4:'Miami', 5:'Dallas', 6:'Houston', 7:'Philadelphia', 8:'Atlanta', 9:'Washington', 10:'Boston', 11:'Phoenix', 12:'Detroit', 13:'Seattle', 14:'San Francisco', 15:'San Diego', 16:'Minneapolis', 17:'Brooklyn', 18:'Tampa', 19:'Denver', 20:'Queens', 21:'Baltimore', 22:'Las Vegas', 23:'St. Louis', 24:'Portland', 25:'Riverside', 26:'Orlando', 27:'Sacramento', 28:'San Juan', 29:'San Antonio', 30:'San Jose', 31:'Pittsburgh', 32:'Cincinnati', 33:'Manhattan', 34:'Cleveland', 35:'Indianapolis', 36:'Austin', 37:'Kansas City', 38:'Columbus', 39:'Charlotte', 40:'Virginia Beach', 41:'Bronx', 42:'Milwaukee', 43:'Providence', 44:'Jacksonville', 45:'Salt Lake City', 46:'Nashville', 47:'Raleigh', 48:'Memphis', 49:'Louisville', 50:'Richmond'}
                 

fipss = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]

for fips in fipss:
    query = FIPSdictionary[fips] + " AND (farm OR mining OR manufacture) AND (inurl:iedconline OR inurl:bizjournal OR inurl:businessinsider)"
    results =search(query,advanced=True, timeout=1000, sleep_interval=5, num_results=3)
    print(fips)
    print(FIPSdictionary[fips])
    print(datetime.now())
    print(query)
    SrcRes = pd.DataFrame(results)
    SrcRes["fipsTitle"] = FIPSdictionary[fips]
    print(datetime.now())

    resultLinks.append(SrcRes)
```